# Run .jar through Windows shortcut passing arguments

Tags: java, windows, jar, shortcut

Is it possible run .jar through Windows shortcut (.lnk) passing arguments?

Comment: Yes. You use the exact some command as you would if you were running it through the command line (ie java -jar YourJar.jar your parameters)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: not that simple any more, I'm afraid.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 7, yes.  You can point the shortcut to `c:\windows\system32\java.exe` or `javaw.exe` as appropriate and include the same arguments you would use on the command line.

In a clean Java 8 installation, not easily. Unfortunately Java 8 no longer puts copies `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` into the system folder, but instead puts symbolic links in a ProgramData folder.  Windows doesn't like shortcuts to symbolic links; sometimes they work, sometimes they don't.  (Even the *same* shortcut might work for some user accounts but not for others.)

(It seems that if you install Java 8 over top of Java 7 it retains the old behaviour, but I haven't investigated this thoroughly yet.)

This simple launcher may be useful; you can create one or more shortcuts to it with the same command line parameters you would have used in the shortcut to javaw.exe.

```
#include <Windows.h>

void NoCRTMain(void)
{
    wchar_t * cmdline = GetCommandLineW();
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    GetStartupInfo(&si);

    if (!CreateProcess(L"C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\javaw.exe", cmdline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Unable to launch Java.", L"runjava.exe", MB_OK);
    }

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

To compile in Visual Studio, you will need to change some project settings:

- Buffer Security Check to No in C/C++ Code Generation
- Ignore All Default Libraries to Yes in Linker Input
- Entry Point to NoCRTMain in Linker Advanced
- Randomized Base Address to No in Linker Advanced ([see commentary here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659232/why-do-my-crt-free-applications-intermittently-crash-on-startup))

(Or you can change the main function from NoCRTMain to WinMain, but then you need to install the C runtime or link it statically.)

---

*Additional:* in Windows 10, if you have two Start Menu shortcuts pointing to the same executable, only one of them will be visible in the Start Menu.  So in this case you need to have multiple copies of the launcher, one for each shortcut.

Comment: I'm using Java SE 7. Can I just create a link to .jar without java.exe?

Comment: @leolegas: a simple link to a jar file seems to work, both in Java 7 and Java 8.  I've never tried doing it that way, I don't know whether adding arguments will work as expected.