# Windows Using Symbolic Link in Shortcut property

Tags: windows, symlink

When the Java runtime is installed on a Windows PC, a folder `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` is created. It contains `javaw.exe` a SYSMLINK (not a .lnk file) to javaw.exe for the current verion of Java, such as `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin\javaw.exe`.

This link can be used from the command line, and also in the registry (handy to add right click actions on files in explorer).

However if I create a shortcut (.lnk) file and set the properties/target to run a java program, I have to use the proper path to javaw, for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin\javaw.exe" -cp S:\JavaClasses\production\WindowsTools Clippo /NS
```

If I use the SYMLINK file, when I double click on the .lnk shortcut a dialog asks me which program I would like to use to open the file.

Keeping the proper path in the shortcut is a pain, because when a new version of Java is installed and the old version removed, I have to update the links.

I could make my own **hard** link, and then I would only have to change that after updating Java, but is there a way to use the links provided by Oracle?

I realise I could use `cmd /C`, but I don't want a console flashing up (hence I am using `javaw.exe` and not `java.exe`

Comment: Depending on your needs, [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29266506/886887).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that as well as the SYMLINK, a direct exe is placed in `C:\Windows\System32` so I can just use:

```
C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe -cp S:\JavaClasses\production\WindowsTools Clippo /NS
```

as the target in the .lnk shortcut file.

**EDIT**

Having read [Harry Johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886887/harry-johnston)'s comment below this is not an ideal answer, thus if anyone knows the answer to the original question of using a SYMLINK, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: In my experience, that executable is *only* present if Java 7 was previously installed on the system.  A clean Java 8 installation won't include it.