# Install a file association to a jar executable

Tags: windows, executable-jar

With my NSIS script, I am trying to install a file association like this:

Set `HKLM\Software\Classes\.my_ext\shell\open\command` default value

with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\my_app_path\my_app.jar" "%1"` or

with `javaw.exe -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\my_app_path\my_app.jar" "%1"` or

with `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\my_app_path\my_app.jar" "%1"`

In first case, it doesn't work at all. (Because jar is not windows executable?)

In second case, it doesn't work at all. (Why?)

In third case, it works, but if USER install a new version of java, in different path, it breaks (my program needs reinstall).

Any solutions?

Comment: In Java 8, the copy of `javaw.exe` that is on the path is a symbolic link, and Windows doesn't like that much.  That might be the problem with the second case, and if so, the obvious resolution to the third case (point at the symbolic link) won't work either.  You might have to ship your own launcher executable.  If so, [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29266506/886887).

Comment: There is nothing NSIS specific here, you could perhaps remove that tag and add the java tag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling javaw.exe directly is never going to work 100% of the time.

The real solution as noted by Harry Johnston in the comments is to use a Java launcher like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). Since you are already using NSIS you might also have some luck by using that as a [simple launcher](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=383136).